# Anuglar - npm audit fix - unhandled exception occurred

Tags: angular

I am creating an Angular app using ng new command. This app contains 7 vulnerabilities and angular suggested to use npm aduit fix to solve these vulnerabilities. 
The question if I don't use npm audit fix the app work and run using npm serve but with npm audit fix the follwoing error appear  the following error appear An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Angular are you using?

If it's lower than 9, then update your cli version

Comment: Currently the angular version is 10. However, when I asked this question the version was 6. Thank you so much.